# Incompatible format types

Tags: c

I'm playing around with strncpy in C and am having some trouble.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char src[] = "Benjamin Franklin";
    char dest[5];

    strncpy(src, dest, sizeof(dest) / sizeof(char));
    dest[5] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", dest);

    return 0;
}
```

which compiles with no errors using:

```
gcc -Wall -g -Werror    test.c   -o test
```

and prints out gibberish like

```
p4��
```

I cannot really understand what I'm doing wrong especially since I have played around with it a lot and been looking online for answers. Perhaps since I am using arrays I am passing the address to printf without realising it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parameters are backwards. `strncpy` copies the second string into the first string, like so.

```
strncpy(dest, src, sizeof(dest) / sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 2):

Two mistakes in your program.

1.You have swapped the arguments of `strncpy`.

2.Also you **cannot access `dest[5]`** because `dest[4]` is the last member you have access to.

Rewrite your program as below and it should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char src[] = "Benjamin Franklin";
    char dest[5];

    strncpy(dest, src, sizeof(dest) / sizeof(char));
    dest[4] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", dest);

    return 0;
}
```

Good to see that you have used `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`. It is always a good habbit to use string manipulation functions with length limit.

Read about `strncpy` [**here**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy).